# OverLay clickable element on Tab

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone, effect, frameworkelement

I want to have graphical feedback for all clickable elements in my app so I have a function that adds an enlarge effect to the icons of buttons by adding a storyboard.Begin() call to their mouseenter and mouseleave, I want to have a similar function for other clickable elements that lights the element up on the mousenter&leave I think it might be able to do it using the Effect property but I am unable to find any documentation on that.

Comment: I've no experience with WP, so dunno if this applies: for a desktop browser SL app I would use the MouseOver VisualState.

Comment: The problem is how to add an overlay, not when to add an overlay.

Comment: @Martin is right, you'll just have to dig into your style templates of the controls you wish to do this to, add an object for MouseOver state (if one doesn't already exist) that looks the way you want for those states, and toggle its visibility with the visualstatemanager of that controls style template. It's not a big deal.